# Is a domain of a holomorphic flow pseudoconvex?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-dynamics

Let $Z$ be a holomorphic vector field on $\mathbb{C}^n$. I would like to know whether (it seems that it is) the domain $D_\phi \subset \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}^n$ of a maximal flow $\phi: D_\phi \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ associated to $Z$ is pseudoconvex i.e. a domain of holomorphy, since I imagine one argues that way. The question is motivated by Forstneric's article [*Actions of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ on complex manifolds*](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~forstneric/papers/1996%20Math.%20Z.pdf) where in the end of the proof of **Proposition 2.1** he uses *Kontinuitatssatz* for $D_\phi$.